# No monomorphism $\mathbb{Z}^3\rightarrow \mathbb{Z}^2$

Tags: group-theory

Should be simple enough, yet I can't show that there are no monomorphisms $\mathbb{Z}^3\rightarrow \mathbb{Z}^2$. (It is true, right?)

Comment: Is $Z$ the integers, $\mathbb Z$?

Comment: Yes, what's the latex code for that?

Comment: The code is: \mathbb Z

Comment: \mathbb{Z}. Also, what kind of map is this? Is it a linear transformation or some other kind of morphism?

Comment: Injective group homomorphism.

Comment: For any homomorphism $f:\Bbb Z^3\to\Bbb Z^2$ think of its kernel, $f^{-1}(0,0)$

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Hint** If $f(x): \mathbb Z^3 \to  \mathbb Z^2$ is any morphism then

$$f(1,0,0), f(0,1,0), f(0,0,1) \in \mathbb Z^2 \subset \mathbb Q^2$$

Then, they must be linearly dependent over $\mathbb Q$ since $ \mathbb Q^2$ is a 2 dimensional $\mathbb Q$-vector space. It is trivial to prove that linear dependence over $\mathbb Q$ implies linear dependence over $\mathbb Z$.

**Alternately** $f$ is given by a $2 \times 3$ matrix with rational entries. Then the reduced row echelon form of $A$ has all rational entries so $\ker(A)$ contains a vector with all entries rational. Prove now that you can find another vector with all entries integer.

Answer (score 2):

**Hint:** Show that given any $x, y, z \in \mathbb Z^2$ there exist *non-zero* integers $a, b, c \in \mathbb Z$ such that
$$ax + by + cz = (0, 0)$$
(You should be able to give an explicit formula for $a, b, c$ in terms of the entries of $x, y, z$)

Next show that if you had a monomorphism $\phi\colon\mathbb Z^3 \to \mathbb Z^2$ then there would be no such $a, b, c$ for the vectors $\phi(0, 0, 1), \phi(0, 1, 0), \phi(0, 0, 1)$.

Answer (score 1):

If we have such that monomorphism $$\phi:\mathbb Z^3\to\mathbb Z^2$$ then according to first theorem of homomorphism we get $\mathbb Z^3\leq\mathbb Z^2$.

Comment: I think it is similar to @Jim's answer.

Comment: @amWhy: $\ddot\smile$

Comment: Greetings, dear friend!! I hope you are feeling much better now, today! I sincerely believe you are a precious asset to this site, both for your answers and help, but also your support of other users and your kindness to OPs! You conduct yourself in a manner which is admirable!

Comment: @amWhy: Thank you very much Amy for your kind words. I mean it Amy. I hope I have been like you say. I wish, I had knew much more than I know now to devote them all. Any way, is there eve. now?

Comment: Yes, it is 21:16 or 9:16 PM for me. It must be very very early in the morning for you!